# Which species is this in below picture? Can you please give me some details or reference link?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

[image: Captured Image]

Can you name this species ? What are some characteristic ?

Size: 2.5 inches to 3 inches

Diameter: 1mm to 2 mm

Can crawl like millipede but little slow.

Always in red colour

Get fold like in one of image tile when touch.

After sometime it able to crawl again.

Has too many thin and small legs both the sides.
Mostly seen in June to August

Don't know if venomous.

Place : North India about 150km south from Himalya Mountain.

Comment: Could you please edit your question add more details, for example: how big was this animal? Where did you find it and at which season? Could you observe any details that might be hard to see on the images? *etc. pp*

Comment: For hints on the information we need for species-id questions you can click on the tag under your post.

Comment: It's a millipede, but which one is very difficult without locality.